# SAS: put in a new table means of samples

Tags: sas, mean

I'm a beginner in SAS and I don't succeed with the following:

I have a table (let's called it table1) that contain 100 samples associated with two variables X and Y:

| Number of sample | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 7 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 11 | 11 |
| 2 | 14 | 2 |
| 2 | 14 | 2 |
| 2 | 17 | -2 |
| ... | ... | .. |

I'd like to create a new table (table2) that contains for each sample the mean of X (I must use proc means).

So the result must be something like this:
[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK4Ob.png)

Can you help me, please?
Thank you in advance,

Larapa

ps: every sample have the same size (3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1qnc9bddfvhzqn105kqitnf29cp.htm&locale=en) covers the operation of `Proc MEANS` in great detail.

For starters, try this example:

```
data have;
input id x y;
datalines;
1   8   7
1   3   4
1   11  11
2   14  2
2   14  2
2   17  -2
;

proc means nway noprint data=have;
  by id;
  var x;
  output out=want(keep=id mean_x) mean=mean_x;
run;
```

[image]